# How do I check my mining hashrate?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ubuntu

I've wrangled an old altcoin mining machine into an ethereum mining rig, it has two Radeon 280X cards in it.

I'm running geth, with two instances of ethminer, one per card.  However the output of ethminer is nothing like what I'm used to with the bitcoin equivalent miners.  It is very minimal.... it just continually prints:

`i  <timestamp>|gpuminer0  WorkLoop 1 #1250db29... #1250db29...`

over and over.

I've seen posts saying you can benchmark your cards with `ethminer -M -G` but that just crashes my rig.

Is there any way to get some kind of additional output that could show hashrate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your use the latest ethminer and pass a high verbosity flag. I'm using `-v 9`. This allows you to follow the hashrate.

```
ethminer -v 9 -G -F http://ethpool.org/miner/0x00000000000000...
```

I'm using the version from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
 ~ $ ethminer --version
ethminer version 1.1.4
Build: Linux/g++/int/Release
```

Here is the result with hashrate:

```
miner  03:51:04.874|ethminer  Got work package:
miner  03:51:04.874|ethminer    Header-hash: a81696b15e04153806d383e37ab7a21ecaa15455c6d5baa4f6d0f0ae057172ee
miner  03:51:04.874|ethminer    Seedhash: 1250db2965df18ca201a546442dab4fdea6f6ed1a13e86ed691dc897dcb9799c
miner  03:51:04.874|ethminer    Target: 00000000dbe6fecebdedd5beb573440e5a884d1b2fbf06fcce912adcb8d8422e
  ℹ  03:51:04.904|gpuminer0  workLoop 1 #1250db29… #1250db29…
  ℹ  03:51:04.933|gpuminer1  workLoop 1 #1250db29… #1250db29…
miner  03:51:05.434|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #a81696b1… : 50855936 H/s = 25427968 hashes / 0.5 s
miner  03:51:06.406|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #a81696b1… : 52051226 H/s = 50593792 hashes / 0.972 s
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It seems I had ethminer version 1.1.3.  Using the `-v 9` flag with 1.1.3 did not help.  When I followed the instructions on https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/wiki/Building-on-Ubuntu it updated it to 1.1.4, and the `-v 9` flag now gives way more output!

Answer (score 0):

Run ethminer -G -M and result of test divide by 1000000

Source: https://ethereumpool.co/how/