# How to quickly check Ethereum Hashing Speed?

Tags: mining

I have 4-5 different GPUs with me. What would be the easiest way to quickly run a Hashing Speed Test on those cards assuming I already have the Drivers for them installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the choice betwen :

1-running [eth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/how-do-i-check-my-mining-hashrate) or ethminer :

```
ethminer -M -G
```

2-using niceHash tool :

https://github.com/nicehash/NiceHashMiner

Comment: Couldn't get Ethminer -M - G to work. NiceHash benchmark works!